# Obtain absolute pixel position of point

Tags: frames, point, gui-emacs

I'd like to obtain the absolute pixel position of the point (i.e. the cursor, **not** the mouse pointer) in the current buffer in a GUI frame, to pass it onwards to an external program.

I don't mind where the pixel position is anchored, e.g. whether to the frame or to the display, as I can easily convert between these, but I haven't found a way to obtain either position within Emacs.

What did I miss?  What function can I use to get the pixel position of the point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `window-absolute-pixel-position`:

> window-absolute-pixel-position is a compiled Lisp function in
>   `window.el'.
>
> (window-absolute-pixel-position &optional POSITION WINDOW)
>
> Return display coordinates of POSITION in WINDOW.
>   If the buffer position POSITION is visible in window WINDOW,
>   return the display coordinates of the upper/left corner of the
>   glyph at POSITION.  The return value is a cons of the X- and
>   Y-coordinates of that corner, relative to an origin at (0, 0) of
>   WINDOW's display.  Return nil if POSITION is not visible in
>   WINDOW.
>
> WINDOW must be a live window and defaults to the selected window.
>   POSITION defaults to the value of `window-point' of WINDOW.