# Distance From the Top Edge of the Window to the Point

Tags: window

Anyway to calculate it?  (either in lines or pixels)

E.g.,

```
 +-------------------+
4|                   | <- top line
5|                   |
6|                   |
7| ■ <- cursor here. |
```

Here it is 3 (or 4, if you prefer to include both lines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lisp
(count-lines (window-start) (point))
```

---

Better method:

```lisp
(keymap-global-set "C-c p"
  (lambda ()
    "Report the distance in lines & pixels."
    (interactive)
    (let ((posn (posn-at-point)))
      (message "%s; %spx"
               (cdr (posn-col-row posn))
               (cdr (posn-x-y     posn))))))
```

Comment: For pixels see [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19556/26163)

Comment: It computes the distance from the 'current' beginning of the window, not the 'very' beginning, so I think it is similar to your question. (I did not fully understand your 'sketch' b.t.w., but now I do :)

Comment: @dalanicolai: "*It computes the distance from the 'current' beginning of the window, not the 'very' beginning, so I think it is similar to your question.*" -- I tested it again, this time more carefully. Yes, it is. Thank you! To avoid overlap between these 2 questions in terms of pixels, I changed my question's title to take only the number of lines into account. ||| Feel free to edit my answer to include the link you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I think it is fine as it is... with the link here in the comments (especially after you edited your question :) Thanks for checking and for updating the question...

Comment: @dalanicolai: In fact, the linked post has some shortcomings -- it seems to calculate some extra distance. I updated my answer; this time it is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a straightforward way to know that, but you can have:

- `(windows-text-height)` , which is the amount of lines in current window
- `(line-number-at-pos)` will return the line number in this buffer.
- `(move-to-window-line)` will be able to move the point to the first visible line using argument 0.

Knowning this writing a piece of elisp code wich will return the desired distance in lines and letting the point where it was is pretty trivial.

`window-line-height` will return the height in pixels of a given line. If you're not using variable fonts it can be used to have the pixel length too, but I'm not sure at all of its accuracy.

Comment: +1 - Thanks. It's just a little roundabout. I think Emacs might have stored such similar values that can be used directly, rather than by moving cursor this way to calculate the distance.

Comment: if it does it should be internally, as usually the used value is the cursor position in the buffer, AFAIK the window handling part is written in C and I don't know what it exposes to elisp

Comment: "*if it does it should be internally*" -- You can take a look at my answer. I see no need to hide this value from the user, which only introduces troubles.